# Tensorflow vs. Pytorch — identical model leads to different results

Tags: python, tensorflow, pytorch

I'm trying to implement 2 identical models in Tensorflow and Pytorch. I am using an extremely simple network. To make sure they are identical I am copying over the initial weights from Tensorflow to Pytorch. This seems to work if I don't fit the model. The initial weights lead to identical predictions.

However, as soon as I run a single training epoch, the models diverge. I am using the same hyperparameters/optimizers. How is this possible?

### Loading the data

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_diabetes
X, y = load_diabetes(as_frame=True, return_X_y = True)
shape = X.to_numpy().shape[1]
```

### Initializing the tensorflow model

```
import tensorflow as tf

feature_inputs = tf.keras.layers.Input(name="feature_input", shape=shape)

hidden_layer = tf.keras.layers.Dense(10)(feature_inputs)
activation = tf.keras.layers.Activation('relu')(hidden_layer)

output = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)(activation)
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=feature_inputs, outputs=output)

keras_weights = model.get_weights()
```

### Initializing the pytorch model

```
import torch
from torch import nn
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader

class MLP(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_shape, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__()
        self.layer1 = nn.Linear(input_shape, 10)
        self.layer2 = nn.Linear(10, 1)

        self.relu = nn.ReLU()

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.layer1(x)
        x = self.relu(x)
        x = self.layer2(x)

        return x
    
class Dataset(torch.utils.data.Dataset):
    def __init__(self, X, y):
        if not torch.is_tensor(X) and not torch.is_tensor(y):
            self.X = torch.from_numpy(X)
            self.y = torch.from_numpy(y)

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.X)

    def __getitem__(self, i):
        return self.X[i], self.y[i]


train_data = Dataset(X=X.to_numpy(), y=y.to_numpy())
trainloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(train_data, shuffle=False)
mlp = MLP(input_shape=shape)

torch_weights = mlp.state_dict()
```

### Copying over initial weights

```
new_weights = {}

for idx, key in enumerate(torch_weights.keys()):
    if key.endswith('weight'):
        new_weights[key] = torch.Tensor(keras_weights[idx].T)
    else:
        new_weights[key] = torch.Tensor(keras_weights[idx])


mlp.load_state_dict(new_weights)
```

### Comparing outputs

The model now give identical predictions when giving it the training data:

```
mlp(torch.from_numpy(X.astype(np.float32).to_numpy()))[0]
# Returns -0.0361
model.predict(X)[0]
# Returns -0.0361313
```

### Running 5 training epochs

For tensorflow:

```
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=1e-8)

model.compile(optimizer, loss="mean_squared_error")
history = model.fit(x=X, y=y,
                    epochs=5,
                    verbose=True,
                    shuffle=False)
```

For pytorch:

```
loss_function = nn.MSELoss()
optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(mlp.parameters(), lr=1e-8)

for epoch in range(0, 5):
    for i, train_data in enumerate(trainloader, 0):
        inputs, targets = train_data
        inputs, targets = inputs.float(), targets.float()
        targets = targets.reshape((targets.shape[0], 1))

        optimizer.zero_grad()
        outputs = mlp(inputs)

        training_loss = loss_function(outputs, targets)

        training_loss.backward()

        optimizer.step()
```

If I now repeat the prediction step, the models have diverged:

```
mlp(torch.from_numpy(X.astype(np.float32).to_numpy()))[0]
# Returns -0.025996
model.predict(X)[0]
# Returns -0.037605
```

Comment: For starter, Tensorflow uses `shuffle=True` as default for `model.fit()`. So the samples both model see are different in order.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. The problem persists unfortunately, even if I put `shuffle=False`, and also put `shuffle=False` in the pytorch `DataLoader`.

Comment: Do they converge to the same point if you continue training to the bitter end?

Comment: @Eureka — they don't no. They just diverge further and result in 2 models with very different training loss even. For example, after 500 epochs, training loss of torch vs tensorflow is 28445 vs 29054

Comment: [Keras defaults to a batch_size of 32](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#fit), while [pytorch's Dataloader deafults to 1](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html)

Comment: Thanks! That solved it :) The models behave the same now!